# Displaying name after login asp.net webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I built a site using the starter site template in Webmatrix that uses a log in.  After a user logs in, it displays near the top "Hello, (email address)!"

Looking at the html code, I see

```
Hello, <a id="logname" class="email" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage">@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</a>!
```

I'm just a beginner with asp.net but can work things out following logic, so what I have done is added a 'Name' field to the database where the email and password is stored and edited the registration page so users can enter their name as well, it writes to the database no problems.

Now I assumed it's just a matter of finding where @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName is referring to the user's email address and make it point to the Name field instead.  However I've searched high and low and can not seem to find it anywhere.

So my next approach was to use code from a Bakery database tutorial that fetches data from a field and modify it to grab the name and display it where I want, the code I tried to use here:

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
```

This appeared to work at first, It displayed "Hello, Ben!" but then if I made any more accounts it started to display them too, so after a while I was getting "Hello, Ben, Steve, Grace, etc..."

Even though I'm a beginner I do realize that this code isn't quite what I need, but something similar that takes that single Name field but only from the currently logged in user... I've googled and searched and seen many people wanting the same thing, except it's using PHP or VB or something that isn't Webmatrix.

If it's a quick answer I'd appreciate the code I need, or otherwise pointed in the right direction, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ironically I find the solution moments after posting the question, so here goes..

This is the code needed to be put at the very top of the file _SiteLayout.chtml

```
@{
var authenticatedUser = "";

if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
authenticatedUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var UserData = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Name FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", authenticatedUser);
authenticatedUser = UserData.Name;
    }
}
```

StarterSite is the name of the database, and UserProfile is the name of the Table, and I labeled the name field Name (explained for the purpose of beginners like me who might be reading this)

Then in the html markup I changed @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName to @authenticatedUser so now it reads:

```
Hello, <a id="logname" class="email" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage">@authenticatedUser</a>!
```

resulting in the desired outcome of it now displaying the user's name instead of their email address.